# How to text search in JQuery

Tags: jquery

I want text search with filter data in jQuery. Suppose I create one input box for text search. Its name is `searchbox`. A complete List appears below the search box.

```
sn. name age destination
1   a     b   test
2   c     c   test1
3   d     d   test
4   v     v   t1
```

I insert any text like `test`. According to this keyword `test` my data appear in bottom side. I cannot use a dataTable.

I tried this but no success

http://www.designchemical.com/blog/index.php/jquery/live-text-search-function-using-jquery/

Please Help

Comment: Could you please add your actual HTML to the question.

Comment: i tryed this :- http://www.designchemical.com/blog/index.php/jquery/live-text-search-function-using-jquery/

Comment: You gave us what you tried, now tell us what's currently wrong and what you want to happen.

Comment: its  only disappear other text but not disappear text with checkbox or radio button

Answer (score 0):

As i understand your problem you want to search in html on webpage. We have many options to do this. I am sharing on of these.

Include jquery on your html page

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Example HTML

```
<div class="span8 col-md-4">
        <div style="width:329px;" class="span12 col-md-8">
         <div class="row-fluid  expandcollapse">
            <div style="float:left;width:134px;font-weight: normal;">
                <span class="permissionsChecked">    
                    &nbsp;<a style="position:relative; top:-4px; text-decoration:none; color:#000; line-height:32px;" data-original-title="Process" rel="tooltip">   
                    <input type="checkbox" data-permitted="1" value="1" name="aa" style="margin-left: 10px" checked="checked" for="L1_1" id="L1_1_2">
                    P1
                    </a>
                    <br>    
                    &nbsp;<a style="position:relative; top:-4px; text-decoration:none; color:#000; line-height:32px;" data-original-title="View" rel="tooltip" >    
                    <input type="checkbox" data-permitted="1" value="4" name="aa" style="margin-left: 10px" checked="checked" for="L1_4" id="L1_4_2">
                        P2</a>
                    <br>    
                    &nbsp;<a style="position:relative; top:-4px; text-decoration:none; color:#000; line-height:32px;" data-original-title="Add">
                        <input type="checkbox" data-permitted="1" value="3" name="aa" style="margin-left: 10px" checked="checked" for="L1_3" id="L1_3_2">
                        P3</a>
                    <br>    
                </span>
            </div>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Now add this final code for search

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#filtersearch").keyup(function(){

            // Retrieve the input field text and reset the count to zero
            var filter = $(this).val(), count = 0;
            // Loop through the comment list
            $(".permissionsChecked a").each(function(){
                // If the list item does not contain the text phrase fade it out
                if ($(this).text().search(new RegExp(filter, "i")) < 0) {
                    $(this).fadeOut();
            // Show the list item if the phrase matches and increase the count by 1
                } else {
                    $(this).show();
                    count++;
                }
            });
            // Update the count
            var numberItems = count;
            $("#filter-count").text("Number of Comments = "+count);
        });
    });
```

In the above javascript code filtersearch is text box in which search data will be entered. If any text matches in given html.

I hope this helps. It working fine a my end.

I created this by using given url by which you tried.
http://designchemical.com/blog/index.php/jquery/live-text-search-function-using-jquery/

Answer (score 0):

Real time table search: [**jsfiddle DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/samuraii/bnq4ggb6/2/)

**HTML:**

```
<input id="srch" type="text" placeholder="search" />
<table id="mtable">
    <!-- -->
</table>
```

**CSS:**

```
tr.hide {display: none;}
```

**jQuery:**

```
$('#srch').on('keyup', function() {
    var searchString = $(this).val();
    var trs = $('#mtable tr:gt(0)'); //omitting the first tr (th)
    trs.removeClass('hide');
    if(searchString) {
        var regx = new RegExp(searchString, "i");
        trs.each(function(i, row) {
           var found = false;
            $(row).find('td').each(function(j, cell) {
                if(regx.test($(cell).text())) {
                    found = true;
                    return false;
                }
            });
            if (found === true)
                $(row).removeClass('hide');
            else
                $(row).addClass('hide');
        });
    }
});
```